# Can't generate jacoco.exec file

Tags: java, sonarqube, testng, pom.xml, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have project with Mockito and TestNG tests. I want to see coverage in Sonarqube. For this I should have jacoco.exec file. When I try to build my project, in result I have "BUILD SUCCESS" without jacoco.exec file in target folder.

There is part of my **pom.xml** file.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    ...
```

command to start build:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar   -Dsonar.projectKey=number20   -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.login=**mylogin**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration hasn't the report execution goal and in addition to this you should not use jacoco exec file because it's deprecated. You should configure the sonar jacoco plugin as suggested in [this official example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/blob/master/doc/jacoco.md).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then jacoco report, generated in the default path, will be imported by sonar.

Comment: Thanks. I took your code and adjust it. So, code in question generates report "jacoco.xml".
But this report is empty :(